# Proper Way to Retry Network Communication

Tags: android

I'm building an app that periodically retrieves data from a website using a recurring alarm and an IntentService.  Before running the update, I check for network connectivity with a ConnectivityManager.

If the ConnectivityManager reports that there is no active network, I wish to try the update again when a network becomes active.  Using a BroadcastReceiver listening for ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION seems like the best way to do this, but what would be the proper way to register/unregister this receiver?

I'm thinking that when the network check fails in the IntentService, that I could register the BroadcastReceiver with the ApplicationContext so it doesn't get unregistered when the service stops.  Could I then unregister the receiver in its own onReceive method when it fires?  Am I way off base?

Some psuedo code examples:

MyIntentService:

```
if ( !isNetworkConnected() )
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver( new MyBroadcastReceiver(), new IntentFilter( ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION );
```

MyBroadcastReceiver:

```
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
    context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver( this );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found the solution to my problem.  Registering the receiver with the ApplicationContext won't work because it will be unregistered when the app process is terminated.

I believe the proper way to handle this is to declare the receiver in the Manifest, and then use PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting to enable/disable the receiver as necessary (in place of my two examples above).

So, I would register it in the Manifest as disabled (enabled=false), then do the following:

MyIntentService:

```
protected void onHandleIntent( Intent intent ) {
    if ( !isNetworkConnected() )
        getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
            new ComponentName( this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class ),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP );
```

MyBroadcastReceiver:

```
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
    getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
        new ComponentName( this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class ),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP );
```